# Using eval on string throws error.

Tags: python, syntax-error, eval

I have a program, which generates a python program as a string which I then need to execute. However, when I try running the string it throws a syntax error.

For example:

```
program = "self.move() self.turnRight() if x > 0: self.turnLeft() else: self.turnRight()"

eval(program)
```

when this runs a syntax error is thrown at whatever the second command is. I'm assuming this is because the string lacks tabs or newlines. Is there a way to automatically add these when the string goes through the eval command?

Comment: Out of curiosity: how are you generating the program?

Comment: a variant of genetic programming

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`eval` can handle only a **single** [Python expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html), and no statement ([simple](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html) or [compound](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html)).

Your string contains multiple expressions *and* statements. You'd have to use `exec` instead:

```
program = '''\
self.move()
self.turnRight()
if x > 0:
    self.turnLeft()
else:
    self.turnRight()
'''

exec program
```

If you were to use a conditional expression you can make it 3 separate expressions:

```
program = ['self.move()', 'self.turnRight()',
           'self.turnLeft() if x > 0 else self.turnRight']
for line in program:
    eval(program)
```

Note that it is always a better idea to implement a more specific language rather than re-use Python and `eval` or `exec`; you'll create more problems than you'll solve, especially when it comes to security.

Comment: So throwing a ```;``` in between each expression doesn't jive?

Comment: @wnnmaw: no, because that's still multiple expressions. That's quite apart from including a statement like `if`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is there anyway to add the newlines and tab's in awell as exec still throws a syntax error./

Comment: @ChrisHeadleand: Not automatically, no. Code meaning changes entirely based on where indentation and newlines are used.